# Get storeviews by group ID in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, store-view

How to get storeview ID (view) by `group_id` (store) in Magento? Basically I want to list storeviews by their `store_id`.

`Mage::app()->getStores()` will get all storeviews, but I want to filter it by specific store group like

```
Mage::app()->getStores()->byGroupId($store_group_id);
```

so i can list all storeviews under a specific store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$groupId = 1;
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);
foreach ($collection as $store) {
    //do something with $store
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id',$store_group_id);
foreach($stores as $store)
{
    print_r($store->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stores = Mage::getResourceModel('core/store_collection')
    # $yourStoreGroupIds can be string or array of group ids
    ->addGroupFilter($yourStoreGroupIds);

foreach ($stores as $store) {
    ...
}
```

Technically the same as Marius answer because `addGroupFilter` uses

```
public function addGroupFilter($groupId)
{
    return $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.group_id', array('in' => $groupId));
}
```

To just get the storeview IDs

```
$storeIds = $stores->getColumnValues('store_id');
```